# Nginx phpmyadmin and magento 2 locally on Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, magento, nginx, phpmyadmin

I'm running magento 2 currently on my local ubuntu machine, and I'd like to install phpmyadmin, but I'm having troubles getting it to actually work.

Basically I want phpmyadmin to run locally so I can just administrate my databases easily, without resorting to command line.

My `.conf` file in `/sites-enabled/` and `/sites-available/` looks like this:

```
upstream backend {
    server  127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen localhost:80;
    server_name magento2.local.dev;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /home/janderson/magento2/;
    root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

    index index.php;
    autoindex off;
    charset UTF-8;
    error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;

    # PHP entry point for setup application
    location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;
        location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
            fastcgi_pass   backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    # PHP entry point for update application
    location ~* ^/update($|/) {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;

        location ~ ^/update/index.php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # Deny everything but index.php
        location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /pub/ {
        location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
            deny all;
        }
        alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /static/ {
        # Uncomment the following line in production mode
        # expires max;

        # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
        location ~ ^/static/version {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }
        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires    off;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
               rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /media/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

        location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires    off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /media/customer/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/downloadable/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/import/ {
        deny all;
    }

    # PHP entry point for main application
    location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   backend;
        fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/xml+rss
        image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;

    # Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
    location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
        allow all;
    }
}

server {
    listen localhost:8080;
    server_name phpmyadmin.local;

    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

Comment: "I'm having troubles getting it to actually work" is a terrible problem description. Tell us what you are doing exactly, what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: Oh, sure thing. I've downloaded and installed phpmyadmin, but when I navigate to the URL I specified in my .conf file (at the end),  phpmyadmin.local the browser just kicks back a "This site can’t be reached" error. I'm running Magento 2 as well at magento2.local.dev

Comment: Do you see anything relevant in your `access.log` or `error.log` files?

Comment: Added code blocks

Answer (score 0):

To manage your databases locally (or even remotely) i would suggest using [MysqlWorkbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) or [SequelPro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) instead of phpmyadmin

Setup is pretty simple, you can put localhost or 127.0.0.1 for 'Host', then correct Port number and username password combination.